Why are there double parentheses around my Python virtual environment in Visual Studio Code?
After updating Visual Studio Code to version 1.88.0, I opened one of my Python projects and noticed that there are double parentheses in my virtual environment: ((env) ).
I'm using the Python extension v2024.4.0

Previously, in the same and all other projects, I had only one pair of parentheses like (env). I have checked, but I didn't find any information about it. I have read that (venv1) (venv2) indicates a double virtual environment, but I don't know if this is the case.
I have tried deleting the env (I have the requirement.txt) or closing/reopening VSCode, but the problem persists. Any suggestions on how to fix it?
I have checked the files: .bashrc, .zshrc, .bash_profile, but everything seems fine. Also, by starting a new project from scratch, the problem persists.

Consider accepting the other answer now that there's a fix (rather than just a recommendation to downgrade).

It's an issue with the Python extension v2024.4.0. Reverting to the previous version, v2024.2.1, fixed this issue for me.


thanks for your reply. I also came to the same conclusion as you. I was checking to see if it was possible to fix it without downgrading.

@Piero This is probably the best place to be updated on how/when it will be fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23184

This was reported on the issue tracker at Double parantheses: "((.venv) )" #23193 and was fixed by the pull request Fix duplicated venv prompt parenthesis #23201. The issue was cause by the earlier pull request Respect VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT when calculating PS1 #23080. Wait patiently for the fix to be released (probably in the April 2024 release of the Python extension, though you can switch to the pre-release channel of the Python extension to get the fix earlier).

...and now with VS Code 1.94.2 on Windows I get zero parentheses...straight up venvphrogz@host, albeit with different colors.
