Why does VS Code Terminal have double parenthesys around the `((.venv) )`?
When I start a new terminal (Terminal->New Terminal) the terminal propt is displayed as
((.venv) ) user@host:~$


Why does the terminal automatically start thinking the .venv is active?

which python3 produces
/home/user/project/.venv/bin/python3

suggesting the venv is indeed active.

Why the double parenthesys?
Why can't I deactivate this environment?

((.venv) ) user@host:~/project$ deactivate
bash: /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.4.0/python_files/deactivate/bash/deactivate: Permission denied

Solution
The problem is related to another issue with a "project" containing multiple virtual environments. (It does not matter where those venvs are.)
A "project" is just the root directory opened by VS Code. With the Python extension installed, VS Code will auto-detect venvs anywhere within the project source tree.
Normally the default behaviour is sensible:

If you have a single venv, it will be detected, and it will be set as the "active workspace environment" (which just means "the default").
You can find this in the Python Extension "Workspace Environments" pane, which is accessed by clicking the Python button from the left hand sidebar.


However - if you have more than one virtual environment, or you do not want the virtual environment to always be active in the terminal by default, this behaviour should be turned off by changing the workspace environment to be the default "Global Environment" which is probably /bin/python3.
With this change, opening a new terminal will not set a venv as active by default, and the terminal will not show (.venv).
Note that it is impossible to deactivate a virtual environment in the terminal if the terminal is set such that when it opens a virtual environment is activated by default.
This relates to the above described bug: If you do have a virtual environment active by default and then you try to activate another one, having found that you cannot deactivate the first one with the usual deactivate command, then the double parenthesis thing will show up like:
((.venv)) (.venv) $

Edit:

Note: VS Code may not automatically detect venvs. I thought it did but you might have to add them manually by running the Python: Select Interpreter command. (CTRL+SHIFT+P by default, or click the environment text in the right hand side of the status bar)


The deactivate command is in the Scripts directory of the virtual environment that you are working in. But it is not clear how you got it activated in the first place.

Same thing is happening to me. Was working fine yesterday, went to open vscode as usual (by typing code . into ubuntu terminal for wsl2) and the terminal window in vscode has the double parentheses and gives the same error code. However, in the regular ubuntu shell, I can activate and deactivate the same virtual env, but it doesnt work in vscode. Also tried setting the python interpreter again (via cntrl+shift+p) but didnt fix it.

Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78282930/env-on-vscode-when-using-virtual-environment-with-python
